# The answers are being cut off

Tags: nodes

I'm using the FAQ module on my Drupal website; I noticed that, on one of the questions, the answer has been completely cut off.

I've tried changing input format (e.g. full HTML instead of WYSIWYG), but I'm still having the same problem.

Is there any problem with the module, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is the Drupal version?

Comment: Does **completely cut off** mean no answer displayed for that question?

Comment: Initially the answers weren't showing but after changing to HTML markup, i shows the first line of the answer and no more. This is not happening on all answers

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to this problem

I went to admin/structure/types/manage/faq/display/teaser and noticed that the format said 'Trimmed'. I changed that to 'default' and the answer is no longer cut off.